# Displaying Meta Box for Categories

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to just display the wordpress categories in a metabox on a different page, the page is custom.

Like a blank page and I am trying to add the wordpress metabox on that page, and be able to add new categories.

[Screencast example](http://screencast.com/t/vA9M6q8aeP) of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please, add snapshots to the Question. If that screencast goes offline, this Question loses meaning and won't help any future visitors (the objective of this site).

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, just call the following function

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_cat_meta' );
function add_cat_meta()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'custom_page' );
}
```

Notice the `custom_page`, replace `custom_page` with your original custom post name, for example if you have following to register a custom post

```
register_post_type( 'restaurant',
    array(...);
);
```

Now to add the category meta box for that custom post you can use

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'restaurant' );
```

Also, if you want to add the category meta box in the `page` section then you can use

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','page');
```

But pages are different than posts and don't require a category.